# Can't use Ionic service like $state or $location inside on swipe left event callback function

Tags: ionic-framework

I Can't use Ionic service like $state or $location inside on swipe left event callback function or onGesture events, so I wrote a code to display the value of $state and $location inside the callback function for those events and it gives me wrong values.

here is what I did to see what's wrong with those services:

```
$scope.onSwipeLeft = function () {
  console.log($state);
  console.log($location);
};
```

And I get this object for both services:
[object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3D9n.png)

Comment: And why is that wrong? How are these dependencies injected in your controller?

Comment: You're right big mistake